# Территориальная локализованность понятия "отечественный"

Tags: лексика

Можно ли слово "отечественный" применить в отношении к другим странам (не России). Например, может ли гражданин Италии по отношению к товару, производимому итальянской компанией, употребить выражение "отечественный товар" (продукт, производство, фильм и т. п.)

Comment: Но итальянец же говорит по-итальянски обычно. Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не рекомендовал такое использование без уточняющего слова.

Хотя формально отечественный может относиться к любому отечеству (известны Отечественные войны, например, - хоть и не без влияния Советской историографии названые, но все-таки никак к СССР/России не относящиеся), но практика употребления все-таки привязывает "отечественный" к России - если нет уточнения.

Впрочем, если нет опасения, что читатель не поймет, о каком отечестве речь, а автору надо непременно вызвать патриотическое чувство, то пусть будет.

Кстати, зачем далеко в Италию ходить?! В украинской русскоязычной прессе с 2014 г. "отечественными" товарами назывались именно украинские. Правда сейчас такое употребление сошло почти на нет - как и актуальность самого понятия.